# SQL Server, calculating total hours per day with multiple breaks

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a query to get the total hours elapsed in a day by someone, however there can be multiple breaks in the times per day.

Here is the query that I  have at the moment.

```
SELECT     
   CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.DorCtrls_Ref, 
   CHINA_VISION_PubCards.CardCode, 
   CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTM
FROM       
   CHINA_VISION_PubCards 
INNER JOIN
   CHINA_VISION_DorEvents ON CHINA_VISION_PubCards.CardCode = CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.CardCode
WHERE     
   (CHINA_VISION_PubCards.CardCode = '000006f1') 
   AND CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.DorCtrls_Ref = '16'
ORDER BY
   CONVERT(Date,CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTM) DESC
```

This query doesn't currently attempt to work out the elapsed time, but here are the results of this so you can see how the data looks.

```
Ref CardCode          EventTM
---------------------------------------
16  000006f1    2015-01-27 07:32:35.000
16  000006f1    2015-01-26 07:38:02.000
16  000006f1    2015-01-26 12:30:54.000
16  000006f1    2015-01-26 13:03:28.000
16  000006f1    2015-01-26 17:28:47.000
16  000006f1    2015-01-23 07:31:10.000
16  000006f1    2015-01-23 12:22:50.000
16  000006f1    2015-01-23 12:47:51.000
16  000006f1    2015-01-23 17:00:20.000
16  000006f1    2015-01-22 07:35:03.000
16  000006f1    2015-01-22 12:28:13.000
16  000006f1    2015-01-22 13:03:12.000
16  000006f1    2015-01-22 16:55:56.000
```

As you can see most days there are 4 records, and i need to work out the elapsed time for them so for example for the 26

```
07:38:02
12:30:54
elapsed time = 4 hours, 52 minutes and 52 seconds
13:03:28
17:28:47
Elapsed time = 4 hours, 25 minutes and 19 seconds
```

So the total elapsed for the 26th would be 9 hours 17 minuets 71

So in the result it would look like

```
 Date     Elapsed
 2015-01-26   9:17:71
```

and so on

We do not need to calculate between 2-3 as the user is not logged on on here.

```
                         1   2        3         4
think of it like this   ON - OFF    BACK ON  - OFF
```

table structure

```
 Name            type         allow null
 Reference          int         Unchecked
 DorCtrls_Ref       int         Checked
 EventsID           tinyint     Checked
 EventTM            datetime    Checked
 CardCode           varchar(50) Checked
 JustificationCode  tinyint     Checked
 RecordIndex        bigint      Checked
 Memo               varchar(50) Checked
 TempltCard         varchar(1024)Checked
 Templtlength        varchar(32)Checked
 TempltDir          varchar(50) Checked
```

Comment: Might be worth having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941659/ms-sql-grouped-sum.

Comment: you hv not fully explained.There are 4 dates  on 26th you hv calculated between 1 & 2 and 3 & 4.Why you hvn't calculated between 2 & 3.Reply back.

Comment: Because the time between 2 and 3 the person is not working think of it like this 
     Needs calculating     time not worked       Needs calculating
           ON - OFF                                            BACK ON -  OFF

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: output 9:17:71 is wrong it should be 9:18:11.Check my latest query.It is very short .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using a very old version of SQL Server, this will work for you:

Test Data:

```
CREATE TABLE Test(Ref int, CardCode varchar(20), EventTM datetime)
insert into Test
select 16,'000006f1','2015-01-27T07:32:35.000' union all
select 16,'000006f1','2015-01-26T07:38:02.000' union all
select 16,'000006f1','2015-01-26T12:30:54.000' union all
select 16,'000006f1','2015-01-26T13:03:28.000' union all
select 16,'000006f1','2015-01-26T17:28:47.000' union all
select 16,'000006f1','2015-01-23T07:31:10.000' union all
select 16,'000006f1','2015-01-23T12:22:50.000' union all
select 16,'000006f1','2015-01-23T12:47:51.000' union all
select 16,'000006f1','2015-01-23T17:00:20.000' union all
select 16,'000006f1','2015-01-22T07:35:03.000' union all
select 16,'000006f1','2015-01-22T12:28:13.000' union all
select 16,'000006f1','2015-01-22T13:03:12.000' union all
select 16,'000006f1','2015-01-22T16:55:56.000';
```

Query:

```
WITH ByDays AS ( -- Number the entry register in each day
SELECT 
    EventTm AS T,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),EventTm,102) AS Day,
    FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT,EventTm)) DayNumber,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT,EventTm)) ORDER BY EventTm) InDay 
FROM Test
)
--SELECT * FROM ByDays ORDER BY T
,Diffs AS (
SELECT 
    E.Day,
    E.T ET, O.T OT, O.T-E.T Diff, 
    DATEDIFF(S,E.T,O.T) DiffSeconds -- difference in seconds
FROM 
    (SELECT BE.T, BE.Day, BE.InDay 
     FROM ByDays BE 
     WHERE BE.InDay % 2 = 1) E -- Even rows
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT BO.T, BO.Day, BO.InDay 
     FROM ByDays BO 
     WHERE BO.InDay % 2 = 0) O -- Odd rows
ON E.InDay + 1 = O.InDay -- Join rows (1,2), (3,4) and so on
   AND E.Day = O.Day --  in the same day
)
--SELECT * FROM Diffs

SELECT Day, 
    SUM(DiffSeconds) Seconds, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), 
    (DATEADD(S, SUM(DiffSeconds), '1900-01-01T00:00:00')),
    108) TotalHHMMSS -- The same, formatted as HH:MM:SS
FROM Diffs GROUP BY Day
```

The result looks like this.

```
Day         Seconds  TotalHHMMSS
2015.01.22  31554    08:45:54
2015.01.23  32649    09:04:09
2015.01.26  33491    09:18:11
```

See the corresponding sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1d31/1

Comment: Hi, the sql server is running 2008, i get this error when i run this with my table instead of test, Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'T'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'T'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'T'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'T'.

Comment: the results of this query are not correct  for example
2015.01.23 39832 11:03:52

We are expecting a result close to 9.18 hours

Comment: I've updated the query so that it uses a similar structure as your original query. Beware, I've modified the query again after some testing (the day grouping wasn't working because of the way I was convrting the day to integer, now it's solved). Now you get the expected results. You can see that also that the odd entries are discarded (day 27 has only one row, so i'ts discarded).

Comment: Hi, i have just run the updated version, i am still getting results that don't match up to the expected, 2015.01.23 41175 11:26:15  is the result but we expect a result around 9.18 hours, Any ideaS?

Comment: @JoshKirkpatrick on day 23, this are the numbers: `12:22:50 - 07:31:10 = 04:51:40` and `17:00:20 - 12:47:51 = 04:12:29`. If you sum `04:51:40 + 04:12:29` you get exactly `08:63:69`, i.e `08:64:09`, i.e. `09:04:09`. So it's working fine, Please, check it carefully.

Comment: i see what your are saying, but we are getting 11:26:15

Comment: Please, rerun the script. Delete all the sample data and create it again. I can assure that when I run the query I get the results I'm showing you. And I'm not parsing dates, so there can be no error. I've just copied and pasted the code in my SSMS again, just in case I made some changes without noticing, and I can assure its working as I show you!

Comment: Thank you for the help, i have tried it with the sample data and it works, but that doesn't really help does it :P any idea? ill post the table structure in the question if that help

Comment: Josh, it does help: this proves this query is well constructed, and works as expected. If it works, with sample data, it must work with your own data. If you need extra help, show your data, how you run your query query, and what is fialing. If you look at my code, you'll see this commented line: '--SELECT * FROM ByDays ORDER BY T'. If you uncomment this line, and run the query until that line, you'll see intermediate results. The same applies to the line `--SELECT * FROM Diffs`. That will help you checking the query execution and finding the possible errors. Don't worry, you'll get it working

Comment: Figured it out, not sure how i missed this for soo long,  We were missing the where clause,  Where DorCtrls_Ref = '16' AND CardCode = '000006f1'  so in my database with all the other data, it was pulling data that it shouldn't

Comment: hi, i don't really understand this query but are all the objects fully qualified apart from the ones in the top section?

Answer (score 1):

From your result you have posted in your question, you can try the below code

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(Ref INT,CardCode VARCHAR(40),EventTM DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT 16,  '000006f1',    '2015-01-27 07:32:35.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 16,  '000006f1',    '2015-01-26 07:38:02.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 16,  '000006f1',    '2015-01-26 12:30:54.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 16,  '000006f1',    '2015-01-26 13:03:28.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 16,  '000006f1',    '2015-01-26 17:28:47.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 16,  '000006f1',    '2015-01-23 07:31:10.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 16,  '000006f1',    '2015-01-23 12:22:50.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 16,  '000006f1',    '2015-01-23 12:47:51.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 16,  '000006f1',    '2015-01-23 17:00:20.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 16,  '000006f1',    '2015-01-22 07:35:03.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 16,  '000006f1',    '2015-01-22 12:28:13.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 16,  '000006f1',    '2015-01-22 13:03:12.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 16,  '000006f1',    '2015-01-22 16:55:56.000'
```

**QUERY**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    -- Gets row number  Order the date
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY EventTM)RNO,  * 
    FROM #TEMP
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    -- Split to hours,minutes and seconds
    SELECT C1.*,C2.EventTM EM,DATEDIFF(S,C1.EventTM,C2.EventTM)DD,
    cast(
        (cast(cast(C2.EventTM as float) - cast(C1.EventTM as float) as int) * 24) 
        + datepart(hh, C2.EventTM - C1.EventTM)
        as INT)HH
    ,CAST(right('0' + cast(datepart(mi, C2.EventTM - C1.EventTM) as varchar(2)), 2)AS INT)MM 
    ,CAST(right('0' + cast(datepart(ss, C2.EventTM - C1.EventTM) as varchar(2)), 2)AS INT)SS    
    FROM CTE C1
    LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.RNO=C2.RNO-1
    WHERE C1.RNO % 2 <> 0
),
CTE3 AS
(
    -- Sum the hours, minute and seconds
    SELECT CAST(EventTM AS DATE)EventTM,
    SUM(HH) HH,SUM(MM) MM,SUM(SS) SS
    FROM CTE2
    GROUP BY CAST(EventTM AS DATE)
)
-- Format the elapsed time
SELECT EventTM,
CASE WHEN MM >=60 THEN CAST(HH+1 AS VARCHAR(10)) END + ':' +
CASE WHEN MM >=60 THEN right('0' + CAST(MM-60 AS VARCHAR(10)),2) END + ':' + 
CAST(SS  AS VARCHAR(10))Elapsed
FROM CTE3
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a6cf86/1) to view result

**EDIT :**

From your query, you can use the below code

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    -- Gets row number  Order the date
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY CONVERT(DateTime,CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTM))RNO,  
           CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.DorCtrls_Ref Ref, 
           CHINA_VISION_PubCards.CardCode, 
           CONVERT(DateTime,CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTM) EventTM
    FROM   CHINA_VISION_PubCards INNER JOIN
           CHINA_VISION_DorEvents ON CHINA_VISION_PubCards.CardCode = CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.CardCode
    WHERE  (CHINA_VISION_PubCards.CardCode = '000006f1') 
     and   CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.DorCtrls_Ref= '16'
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    -- Split to hours,minutes and seconds
    SELECT C1.*,C2.EventTM EM,DATEDIFF(S,C1.EventTM,C2.EventTM)DD,
    cast(
        (cast(cast(C2.EventTM as float) - cast(C1.EventTM as float) as int) * 24) 
        + datepart(hh, C2.EventTM - C1.EventTM)
        as INT)HH
    ,CAST(right('0' + cast(datepart(mi, C2.EventTM - C1.EventTM) as varchar(2)), 2)AS INT)MM 
    ,CAST(right('0' + cast(datepart(ss, C2.EventTM - C1.EventTM) as varchar(2)), 2)AS INT)SS    
    FROM CTE C1
    LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.RNO=C2.RNO-1
    WHERE C1.RNO % 2 <> 0
),
CTE3 AS
(
    -- Sum the hours, minute and seconds
    SELECT CAST(EventTM AS DATE)EventTM,
    SUM(HH) HH,SUM(MM) MM,SUM(SS) SS
    FROM CTE2
    GROUP BY CAST(EventTM AS DATE)
)
-- Format the elapsed time
SELECT EventTM,
CASE WHEN MM >=60 THEN CAST(HH+1 AS VARCHAR(10)) END + ':' +
CASE WHEN MM >=60 THEN right('0' + CAST(MM-60 AS VARCHAR(10)),2) END + ':' + 
CAST(SS  AS VARCHAR(10))Elapsed
FROM CTE3
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the response, seems to work beautifully however for some reason the dates are not ordered for example here are the first 10 results 

2010-02-02 7:92:3152
2013-04-15 2:31:7402
2013-01-22 1:96:7978
2010-04-26 7:94:2423
2009-11-11 6:62:2127
2012-10-31 1:32:8459
2013-10-15 3:74:7062
2014-09-18 2:52:6515
2010-07-18 14:26:619
2012-08-09 1:78:8121

As you can see the days are all over the place, any idea why?

Comment: Are you telling about the order after you got result from my query? @Josh Kirkpatrick

Comment: Yes this is the order that the results are in

Comment: Pretty simple. Add **ORDER BY EventTM** in the last line. @Josh Kirkpatrick

Comment: Hi, running the edit version i get this result 
2015-01-23 63:02:43  for the 26th, which i assume equates to 63 hours that day.... and running the other version. gets me 2015-01-23 2:29:6892 which im assuming is 2.29 hours,  we know we should be expecting a result like 9:03:69

Comment: How many records are there in your table on 23rd? @Josh Kirkpatrick

Comment: there are 4  

 2015-01-23 07:31:10.000,
 2015-01-23 12:22:50.000,
        2015-01-23 12:47:51.000,
 2015-01-23 17:00:20.000,

Answer (score 1):

Try this,The out put is correct .

```
your output is wrong.9:17:71 is wrong.it should be 9:18:11.

    Declare @t table(Ref int, CardCode varchar(20), EventTM datetime)
insert into @t
select  16,'000006f1','2015-01-27 07:32:35.000' union all
select  16,'  000006f1','2015-01-26 07:38:02.000' union all
select 16,'  000006f1','2015-01-26 12:30:54.000' union all
select 16,'  000006f1','2015-01-26 13:03:28.000' union all
select 16,'  000006f1','2015-01-26 17:28:47.000' union all
select 16,'  000006f1','2015-01-23 07:31:10.000' union all
select 16,'  000006f1','2015-01-23 12:22:50.000' union all
select 16,'  000006f1','2015-01-23 12:47:51.000' union all
select 16,'  000006f1','2015-01-23 17:00:20.000' union all
select 16,'  000006f1','2015-01-22 07:35:03.000' union all
select 16,'  000006f1','2015-01-22 12:28:13.000' union all
select 16,'  000006f1','2015-01-22 13:03:12.000' union all
select 16,'  000006f1','2015-01-22 16:55:56.000'

;with CTE as
(
select *,row_number()over(partition by dateadd(d,0,datediff(d,0,EventTM)) 
order by EventTM)rn  from @t 
)
,CTE1 as
(
select Ref,CardCode,EventTM, rn oddrn,0 TimeElapse from CTE where rn%2<>0
union all
select a.Ref,a.CardCode,a.EventTM, rn ,datediff(s,b.EventTM,a.EventTM) 
from CTE a
inner join CTE1 b on 
dateadd(d,0,datediff(d,0,a.EventTM))= dateadd(d,0,datediff(d,0,b.EventTM)) 
and a.ref=b.ref
and a.rn-b.oddrn=1 and a.rn%2=0
)

select EventTM,cast((convert(varchar(5),TimeElapse/3600) +':'+ 
convert(varchar(5),TimeElapse%3600/60) 
+':'+ convert(varchar(5),TimeElapse%60)) as datetime)  from 
(select dateadd(d,0,datediff(d,0,EventTM)) EventTM,sum(TimeElapse) TimeElapse 
from cte1 
where TimeElapse>0
group by dateadd(d,0,datediff(d,0,EventTM)))tbl
```

Comment: Hi, i tried this version, the query has been running for over 6 minuets and no results so far so i'm not sure what's going on here

Comment: No it is giving me output in less than a second.just copy paste exactly and run .I am using sql server 2008.Or you must be mistaken for some other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to test this myself but it may give you a good start. I would use a cursor if you want to keep it in SQL although I'd probably prefer to do it in CLR. Others may have a better method but you can try this:

```
Declare @olddate datetime,
    @date datetime
DECLARE @Table table (Ref int, CardCode varchar(20), EventTM datetime, ElapsedTime varchar(30))

Declare cur_mycursor Cursor fast_forward for

SELECT     CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTM
FROM       CHINA_VISION_PubCards INNER JOIN
CHINA_VISION_DorEvents ON CHINA_VISION_PubCards.CardCode = CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.CardCode
WHERE     (CHINA_VISION_PubCards.CardCode = '000006f1') 
and      CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.DorCtrls_Ref= '16'
Order by CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTM desc

Open cur_mycursor
Fetch next from cur_mycursor into @olddate

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
Fetch next from cur_mycursor into @date
INSERT INTO @Table (Ref, CardCode, EventTM, ElapsedTime)
SELECT     CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.DorCtrls_Ref, 
   CHINA_VISION_PubCards.CardCode, 
   CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTM,
   case when Convert(varchar, @date, 112) = Convert(varchar, CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTM, 112) 
        then Cast(datediff(mi, @date, CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTM) / 1440 as varchar) + ' days ' +
             Cast(datediff(mi, @date, CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTM) % 1440 / 60 as varchar) + ' hours ' +
             Cast(datediff(mi, @date, CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTM) % 1440 %60 as varchar) + ' minutes'
        else '0'
    end as elapsedtime
FROM       CHINA_VISION_PubCards INNER JOIN
   CHINA_VISION_DorEvents ON CHINA_VISION_PubCards.CardCode = CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.CardCode
WHERE     (CHINA_VISION_PubCards.CardCode = '000006f1') 
and      CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.DorCtrls_Ref= '16' and CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTM = @olddate
Order by CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTM desc
Set @olddate = @date
end
close cur_mycursor

Select * from @Table order by EventTM asc

deallocate cur_mycursor
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, i'm not great with SQL and quite a few things in this query i don't understand however straight off the bat i am getting this error

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 'next'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near 'next'.

Comment: I just tried it with the fix, the query runs now however it's doing something i have never seen before. http://imgur.com/ykArYuT

Comment: @JoshKirkpatrick lol, apologies again, maybe the edited will work better?

Comment: This time i'm getting this returned, 0 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)

Over and over again

Comment: Using cursors when an operation can be done with a batch operation is not the best idea. It usually have a performance hit. Please, see the other proposed solutions.

Comment: The edited should be right now, I didn't have my variables set to datetime for some reason which is why you were getting blank rows. As JataBe mentions though, the other answer may be more efficient. I did just do this one as it was all I could think of at the time whilst I was in the middle of my day job :-/